# ffmpeg unable to resave one channel in mp4 file

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, wav

I have an mp4 audio file with two channels: left and right, and I need to save the only one (say right) channel to another file. Using `ffmpeg` I'm able to do this easily in a wav format, but saving it in an mp4 format causes troubles for me. I was able to do this but the resulting file is of the same size as the source file. While the wav file becomes smaller when removing one channel from it. Is it possible to make the one-channel mp4 file to be smaller then the source file?

I've tried a lot of ways so far, some of the working combinations are:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -map_channel 0.0.1 right.mp4
```

The next command gives an error

> Unsupported channel layout "1 channels (FR)" Error initializing output
> stream 1:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream
> #1:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:a]channelsplit=channel_layout=stereo[left][right]" -map [left] _.wav -map [right] right.mp4
```

Same conversion to a wav file works fine but further conversion back to a mp4 results in a same error.

I also tried to convert a wav file with only right channel back to mp4 with a `vlc` but it produces a file with the size equal to a source mp4 file.

Answer (score 1):

edit: I was wrong on my initial answer. Here is the correct take.

The error says it all:

```
Unsupported channel layout "1 channels (FR)"
```

The `channelsplit` filter is apparently broadcasting the name of the channel that you selected, and the audio encoder is aware of the channel name (FR) and there isn't a mono layout that is just of the FR channel. An easy fix is to use `-ac 1` to re-label it as 'mono':

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 \
  -af "channelsplit=channel_layout=stereo:channels=FR" \
  -ac 1 right.mp4
```

This being said, this should be identical to the first approach with `-map_channel 0.0.1`, and you may not observe any (substantial?) change in file size from the original stereo version possibly because AAC codec can identify the sameness of the left & right channels and code very efficiently.

<strike>MP4 format does not allow you to have mono audio. You need to map the desired source audio channel to stereo with the same signal on its left and right channels:</strike>

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -map_channel 0.0.1 -ac 2 right.mp4
```

`-ac 2` essentially duplicates `0.0.1` source channel to left and right

Comment: My command with `map_channel` works fine, but the resulting mp4 has the same size as the original. My question was about can I have a one-channel mp4 so it's size will be smaller the two-channel, as you pointed out isn't possible. Thanks

Comment: You're right. My apology for miscomprehending your question. I've updated my response to show how to avoid the error, and also my take on why stereo->mono change shows no benefit.

Comment: Thank you for sheding some light on how all this channels stuff works. Could you suggest some article that will let me understand it beter (I've never worked with audio before)

Comment: Tbh, I'm also learning as I'm trying help others :D As far as the channel manipulation goes, [FFmpeg documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/documentation.html) is my bible, but you've probably been there already. Audio channel info is somewhat hidden in [Utilities Section](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Channel-Layout). As for the codecs, probably the best place to start is the wikipedia. Here is [its page on AAC codec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Audio_Coding) that you are using.